# Elasticsearch, when document is stored does it get split up into different shards?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am reading a book about elasticsearch however it is unclear to me, tried looking at the documentation(doesn't really talk much about its arcitecture), other posts however cannot seem to find related posts.

say I have a document as follows:
`{message: "hello world Welcome to Elastic"}`

1. when it gets inserted into elasticsearch it will go through analyze phase and become ["hello", "world", "welcome", "to", "elastic"]
   so now each term is spread across different shards?
2. Elasticsearch is referred to as "distributed data storage" is it because document gets distributed into different shards?
   In the book, it says "if you create elasticsearch in distributed environment, one index can be distributed into different nodes". Does this mean subset of shards that belong to index1 is being stored in another index?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. No a document is never split across different shards. The document ID is hashed and that hash defines on which shard the document will get stored. The fields of a document will get analyzed into tokens but all those by-products will get stored on the same shard as the document.
2. Distributed data storage means that indexes are partitioned into shards and those shards can be located on different nodes. So, let's say you have one index with 2 primary shards. If you have 1 node in our cluster, it will get both shards of your index. If you have two nodes, each node will get one primary shard. If you have three nodes, then one node will get nothing because shards cannot be split further. If you decide to add one replica shard per primary shard, then you have four shards (2 primary + 2 replicas) and then the third node will certainly get at least one shard (primary or replica).

Since a picture is worth thousand words, here is one that illustrates pretty well the distributed nature of Elasticsearch.

[image: Cerebro]

So the main take aways are:

- An index is partitioned into one or more primary shards (= the bold green squares)
- Primary shards can have 0+ replica shards (= the dashed green squares)
- All primary and replica shards of an index belongs to that index (= the `logstash-*` columns)
- A cluster can have several data nodes (= the `elasticsearch-*` rows)
- Shards (whether primary or replicas) are distributed among all data nodes of your cluster (= all the cells in the above picture). Also worth noting that a primary and its replica shard(s) can never be located on the same node

Comment: thanks for really informative answer. One more question, if you only have one node, and using default number of shards, replica shards, in such case since replica shard cannot belong to same index as its primary, where are they stored?

Comment: They would be in unassigned state and your cluster would be yellow (instead of green). Having replicas necessarily means to have more than one node. Yellow state is a perfectly working cluster, however, you have no failover or fault-tolerance.