# What exactly is a shard?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am going through the documentation,

> An index can potentially store a large amount of data that can exceed the hardware limits of a single node. For example, a single index of a billion documents taking up 1TB of disk space may not fit on the disk of a single node or may be too slow to serve search requests from a single node alone.
>
> To solve this problem, Elasticsearch provides the ability to subdivide your index into multiple pieces called shards. When you create an index, you can simply define the number of shards that you want. Each shard is in itself a fully-functional and independent "index" that can be hosted on any node in the cluster.

What exactly constitutes elastic search shard ? Is it a lucene thread which is configured with memory ? Is it possible to adjust setting for individual shard ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59064603/4604579) which should help, I can add that a shard actually wraps a full-fledge Lucene search engine.

You cannot change settings for individual shards, instead you can change settings at the index-level and Elasticsearch will apply them on the index shards.

So Elasticsearch gives you the ability to split the workload on an index among all the shards (i.e. Lucene engines) of that index which are located on different nodes.

Very simply put: **Elasticsearch = distributed Lucene** !

Comment: thanks a lot for informative answer, may i assume the shard is "running/runtime" lucene engine - which evetually had some states like start, unassigned etc ?

Comment: Lucene is completely hidden, you never get to interact with it. If a shard has been assigned to a node, you can be certain that the internal Lucene engine is running.